# conditional binary operator expected with Do and ssh connection

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

This is part of my code that I working to find a word in a remote server connecting via ssh to that server

```
filename=test.repo
word=fail
exists=$(grep -c $word $filename)
file_server=$1

for i in $(cat $file_server)
    do echo ''; echo $1 ;
    ssh $i "printf '\e[33m'; hostname; printf '\e[0m\n]' ;
    cd /etc/yum.repos.d/;
    grep -c $word $filename;
    echo $exists;
    if [[ $exists -gt 0 ]];
        then printf 'Keyword found, cleanup starts \n';
            else printf ''$word', was not found, nothing to do here with '$filename'. \n';
fi"

done
```

This works with just the Do command, but if I add the if [[$exist -gt 0]]; , this got an error

bash: -c: line 4: conditional binary operator expected
bash: -c: line 4: syntax error near `;' bash: -c: line 4:`      if [[ -gt 0]];  '

any suggestion

Comment: `$exists` is set in the script "outside" of the `ssh`.  The other server (represented by `$i` here) does not know about `$exists` that you set on your origin server.  Variables and their values are not "sent" or copied over to a remote server you connect to via `ssh`.

Comment: Add spaces after `[[` and before `]]`.

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop to iterate over a file. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line should be cut from the beginning of the script:
exists=$(grep -c $word $filename)

And replace the call to grep inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What I do, with some help of a colleague to fix this avoid using the variable on the ssh session.

```
file_server=$1
filename=testfile.repo
keyword=testword


if [[ -z $1 ]]
then
        printf "\t\e[0;31m==================== ERROR ======================\n"
        printf "\tServer list not found\e[0;0m\n"
        exit 1
fi

for i in $(cat $file_server)
    do echo ''; echo $1 ;
    ssh $i "printf '\e[33m'; hostname; printf '\e[0m\n';
        cd /etc/yum.repos.d/;
        if grep -q $keyword $filename;
    then
        printf '\e[33m$keyword found, cleanup starts\e[0m\n';
        sed -i.BAK '/^failovermethod=/d' $filename
        grep failovermethod $filename;
        printf '\e[33mBackup file created with the $keyword with this name $filename.BAK\e[0m\n';
        grep 'failovermethod' pgdg-redhat-all-test.repo.BAK;
    else
        printf '\e[33m${keyword^^}\e[32m, was not found, nothing to do here. \e[0m\n';

    fi;";

done
```